# Liberty Reserve Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am trying to integrate Liberty Reserve API into my website to accept payments like Paypal and Payza IPN.
Is there a sandbox available to test because I can't seem to find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved this issue. Yes testing is available but it's not like Paypal and Payza sandbox.

Comment: without further details this answer is .. not very helpful ;-)